# Latest instance of sql row without self join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Input Rows

```
userid        |  no      |  version_no
--------------|----------|--------------  
abc           | 100      | 1  
abc           | 2        | 1  
abc           | 101      | 2  
abc           | 3        | 2
def           | 9        | 1
def           | 1        | 2
def           | 6        | 3
def           | 8        | 4
```

I'd expect the output of the query to be:

```
abc      |  104       |  2
def      |  8         |  4
```

Can I do this using any any method other than self-joins ? I am using sql server. 
The output no for abc - 104 is the sum of 101 and 3 from the inputs. If I have multiple rows for the latest version, I only want to display the sum of no's.

Apologies for editing the post multiple times.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And were does `104` come from? It's not part of the sample data.

Comment: MySQL? Access? MS Sql Server? And I think it's `SELECT userid, sum(no), version_no FROM <solution to OP's problem>`

Comment: I am using sql server. The output row no - 104 is the sum of 101 and 3 from the inputs

Comment: so what is the logic behind `101 + 3`  why not `100 + 2` or `100+2+101+3`

Comment: I only want to display the sum of no's for the latest version_no

Comment: So why you dont want self-joins? with one user `TOP 1` could solve it, now with more user at leat you would need a subquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply a ranking function after aggregation:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 ( SELECT userid, SUM(no) AS no_sum, version_no,
      ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (PARTITION BY userid 
            ORDER BY version_no DESC) AS rn
   FROM table_name
   GROUP BY userid, version_no
 ) AS dt
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Hey dnoeth, this is exactly what i was looking for. Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

**Edited to reflect edits to question:**

To limit to the most recent version add a `HAVING` clause, which acts in a similar manner to the `WHERE` clause, but filters columns aggregated by `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT userid, SUM(no) AS no_sum, version_no
FROM table_name
GROUP BY userid, version_no
HAVING version_no=MAX(version_no)
```

Comment: Add `top 1` and `order by version_no DESC`

Comment: Hey Anthony E, I only want to display the sum of no's for the latest version_no. I don't want to display data from my earlier version_no = 1

Comment: See my edit. You can also use a descending sort on the version number and use `LIMIT 1` to get the most recent.

Comment: top 1 wont work for me because i probably have multiple userid's

Comment: Ok, your original question is more clear. You can simply use a  `MAX version_no` and simplify the group by

Comment: Sort version doesnt work, having does. Also `LIMIT` isnt part of sql server.

Answer (score 1):

To get just the aggregated results for the highest version_no without a self join, you can use `TOP` and `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT TOP 1
     userid,
     sum(no),
     version_no
FROM your_table
GROUP BY userid, version_no
ORDER BY version_no DESC
```

`TOP 1` will return only the first record in the result set ordered by the `ORDER BY` clause of `version_no` in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

use having to select row with highest version_no

```
SELECT userid, SUM(no) 
FROM table_name t1
having version_no = (select max(version_no) from  table_name  t2 WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id)
GROUP BY userid, version_no
```

Comment: You need to add a correlation to `user_id`

Comment: @dnoeth  hi, what kind of correlation ?

Comment: *SELECT userid, SUM(no) 
FROM table_name AS t1
having version_no = (select max(version_no) from  table_name AS t2 **WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id**)
GROUP BY userid, version_no;* Otherwise you don't get `abc`